# Best way to store custom values in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, database

Is there a good (recommended) way to store custom values in Drupal 7? I've looked into variable_set / variable_get, but then read a comment suggesting NOT to use those for the purpose that I'm needing (unless I completely misunderstood). Here's the comment that I'm referring to:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7

"All data created by variable_set() is loaded from the database at bootstrap. Calling variable_get() doesn't perform the database request to get you the data, it simply declares the $conf global and returns the variable you've asked for. Therefore, don't carelessly use variable_set() to store lots of data that you will only use on individual pages or in custom methods. Use your own little table and storage functions for that."

Basically, I'd like a place to store a couple of values, so that I can avoid having to hard code those values within my custom module code. For instance, I'd like to store a current Reporting Year (i.e. 2011), and a current Data Entry Year (i.e. 2012). Is this just something that I'd need to create my own table for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no need to create your own table for that. Your use case is a perfect example of what *should* be stored in the variables table (in my opinion).

Since the data isn't particularly volatile, and you only have a couple of values, I can't see any benefit to adding a custom table for it.

If you start finding yourself storing a lot of data in variables, for example a single different variable for each node of a certain content type, that's when you need to start looking at a custom table.

Comment: Where would I place the actual variable_set($breakfast, 'donuts')? Is it then accessible anywhere that I call variable_get($breakfast)?

Comment: You can either define it in $settings.php: `$conf['your_variable'] = 'value';` or build a settings form for it, see system_settings_form().

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using these to to replace constants in your code, then [`variable_set`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) / [`variable_get`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) is the appropriate thing to use.

It is not the best approach to persist data between pages (eg, emulate a cookie) or to avoid having to make a custom database table.

Comment: Note that "not the best approach" actually means "completely wrong approach" if variable_set() is going to be called on public pages/all pages. I had yet another case of a hardcoded variable_set() call in template.php (outside of a function of course. Took me a moment to find it, that's even more crazy than doing it in a .module file) today on a site that I was tasked to do a performance analysis, that's a nice way to completely kill the performance of your site.

Comment: @Berdir: what would you suggest?

Comment: @cmmsites: Well, anything else, put it into session, a custom table, cache, get arguments, whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said here,

```
$foo=variable_get('YOURMODULE_current_reporting_year', '2011');
```

or

```
$bar=variable_get('YOURMODULE_current_data_year', '2012');
```

isn't going to really hurt anything.

You could even set up a module admin settings page to set these if/when your years change. Now, if your module was going to variable_set() these all over the place, that would be another story.

Of course, if you are super concerned with the DB, you could also

```
define('YOURMODULE_CURRENT_REPORTING_YEAR', 2011);
define('YOURMODULE_CURRENT_DATA_YEAR', 2012);
```

and then this would work:

```
$foo=YOURMODULE_CURRENT_REPORTING_YEAR;
$bar=YOURMODULE_CURRENT_DATA_YEAR;
```

but you would have to manually change those defines when necessary.

Comment: Similarly to my response to Clive above, where would I place the actual variable_set()? Same question applies to the define()? I just want to ensure that whatever I approach I take I'm able to access those Report Year and/or Current Data Year values from anywhere.